# MS Access 2016: how to enter a concatenated field into a table from a form

Tags: forms, ms-access, concatenation

TblEmployees has Fname, Lname and EmployeeName fields.  EmployeeName should be Fname + Lname (i.e. John Doe).  I want to enter Fname and Lname in a form FrmEmployeeData, and update TblEmployees with Fname, Lname and EmployeeName.
If  FrmEmployeeData has as Data Source TblEmployees, how do I get the concatenated [Fname]&" "&[Lname] into the EmployeeName field of the table?

I also tried changing the DataSource of FrmEmployeeData to a query QryConcatenateFname&Lname where EmployeeName:[Fname]&" "&[Lname].  This gave the correct "John Doe" in the query result but I could not get it to update the TblEmployees.

What am I doing wrong?  Thx.

Comment: You don't. When you need the full name, use a _select_ query having the field `FullName: [Fname] & " " & [Lname]`.

Comment: Or calculate the concatenation in textbox.

Comment: Or use Calculated type field in table. Has pros and cons but AFAIK, it works just fine (I've never implemented). This is a dynamic calculated value and cannot be edited.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are learning access as this question is really too simple for stack overflow.  Instead consult an Access book at your library or start finding Youtube vidoes and tutorials on the internet.  Having said that here is a start:

[image]

Access gives you the ability to add a calculated field to a table in the design tab by treating it as a DataType.  You can also add lookups and some data validation.  **Never do any of that!!**  Use forms to enter and search the data, and use reports to print the data.

A simple yet quite incomplete explanation is that as your database expands into multiple related tables you will find that entering the data directly into the tables is error prone for the database designer yet alone the clients.  Because any observation will be distributed across multiple tables it becomes easier and easier to forget one or make a mistake as you add more and more tables.

Access is designed for quickly making simple forms for the tables in your database.  If your relationships are already entered using the Relationships tool Access even generates starter forms that handle 1 to many relationships.  Just click on a table and under home then forms group on the ribbon choose either form or form wizard and start playing with your new forms properties:

[image]

if you don't see the properties (hit f4 in most cases).  Seriously every control has properties you can play with.  In particular look at the control sources and for the form itself (hit the top left corner to select the form) check out the default view property.

I happened to include EmployeeName as a string in tblEmployees but there was no need other than having access put the EmployeeName textbox on the form.  I would have to go back and delete EmployeeName from the table which is about the same effort as adding the textbox to the form myself.  Below I show how to set the control source for EmployeeName to the usual FullName calculation

[image]

```
=[Fname] & " " & [Lname]
```

Access forms by default have both data entry and search capabilities.  Play with the record selector highlighted at the bottom of the beautified form below.  You can edit any record you see and the changes will appear in the table.  If you go past the last record you can add a new record.

[image]